# How to stop a serenity jbehave test and set test out come

Tags: jbehave, serenity-bdd

I'm using serenity core and JBehave. I would like to stop the test and set test outcome as PASS based on some condition if the condition fails test continues.

How could I stop the JBehave test during suite execution and set PASS? And then the suite continues with another test.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, JBehave is designed to optionally stop a test upon failure only.  By default it will fail an entire scenario and continue with any other scenarios in the story as applicable.

In situations like this, I believe your only solution is through the steps methods themselves.  Check your "pass" condition in the steps method and then continue the code only if that condition fails.  It's possible your story's scenario definition is not concise enough?  Keep it to a simple Given, When, Then instead of breaking the steps up in too detailed a manner.